# Is there a way to auto create and drop mongodb everytime spring boot is run?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm currently on a Spring Boot + MongoDB project.

There is a DDL-AUTO function for sql if I implement this in `application.properties`.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
```

**I want to know a way to reset my mongodb database everytime I initailize Spring Boot.**

I've found out that some people say it is possible using HibernateOGM.
But I'm wondering if I cannot do the exact same tesk without it (since HibernateOGM is deprecated).

This is my `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    ...
}
```

This is my `application.properties`.

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.data.mongodb.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.data.mongodb.database=${DB_NAME}
spring.data.mongodb.port=${DB_PORT}
spring.data.mongodb.host=${DB_HOST}
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```